# Browser does not react on a Redirect response from AuthorizationFilter

Tags: redirect, browser, servlet-filters, saml-2.0

JSF sends an redirect to the webbrowser. But for some strange reason the browers doesn't react on the redirect.
I have been able to identify when this happend, but not why it happend.

The system is coded in Primefaces 4.0, Glassfish 3.1.2.2, JSF 2.1.11.

The receipt for creating the problem is:
1.) Have a session-timeout (for test purpose it is set to 2 minutes).
2.) Login to the module.
3.) Wait to the session timeout expire.
4.) Press the logout button.

5.) The logoutbutton will fire away an event to the login/logout module. Which will contact the IDP (SingleSignOn/SingleSignOut provider).
An response that the user is not valid will be recived. The login/logout module, will response back to the user with an Redirect URL.
The webbrowser will get the response. But do nothing.
It is possible to see this with the F12 button in the browser (Chrome).
If I take that response URL and paste it into another browser/tab. The browser will send the user to the right location. In this case, 
to the IDP:s inlogging module.

Here is where it gets a little bit confusing for me.
If I open a clean new browser. With no session active. I take the URL to the "secure" page, and enter it to the URL-line. Press Enter, and
I can see that the browser will try to access the page. But then an authorizationFilter will fetch the request/response. 
Identify the users as not logged in user. Then send the user (response.redirect) to the inlogging module.
Which is the right behaviour.

When it comes to the problem describe above. I can see in every log, and in the browser development window. That the same thing happend
when the session times out. 
The only differences what I can see, is that the users browsers is not redirected to the loginmodule.

From a user perspective, it seems like the logout button is dead.

This is an problem with a twist. On that page, there is a button to download a file. If the user press that button. The file will be downloaded.
Once the file have been downloaded. There is no problem for the logout button to redirect the user to the right page.

So here is another question on the same topic. Why? It seems like the system "refresh" it self, and become active again.

Overview of the different modules:

Loginmodule: Redirect the user to the LoginModule, and get a answer back if the user is authorized for login or not. I.e. the IDP sends an SAML to the loginmodule.
IDP: An identity Provider. 
GUI-module: The module that the user tries to access. Primefaces 4.0, JSF 2.1.11
The GUI module have an AuthorizationFilter, that checks so that the user is authorized and authenticated (got a valid not tampered SAML) to be on the GUI module.

I would be really happy for any hint suggestion that could lead to that I can solve this problem. Or even better, an clear instruction how to solve it.